# How much light does a Coure Eladrin familiar shed, and how do they see?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars, vision-and-light

I am considering asking my DM if I can summon a Coure for my 9th level duskblade and am trying to anticipate problems that may arise.

Coure prefer star filled nights (per their description). Does that mean they have low-light vision? When in incorporeal form how would their light interact with darkness spells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because a coure (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 168-9) has the subtype [eladrin](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_eladrinsubtype&alpha=E), the coure has low-light vision. This *is* noted in the *Monster Manual* (2003) in the eladrin entry (96) yet absent from the glossary's eladrin entry (308). The premium edition of the *Monster Manual* (2012) corrects what appears to be the earlier printing's omission, granting all eladrins low-light vision by virtue of their subtype.

(Both the coure's type [outsider](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#outsider) and subtype eladrin also grant the coure darkvision 60 ft. These, of course, don't combine for cumulative distance.)

Absent other information, it appears the coure can shed light so as to provide [shadowy illumination or bright illumination](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#vision-and-light) (*Player's Handbook* 164-5). While a the coure's ability to assume ball-of-light form *is*  supernatural, you'll have to ask the DM if the *light* that the form can  subsequently shed is *also* magical, therefore capable of dispelling magical darkness.

Note that a coure can't typically be gained through the feat Improved Familiar (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 200). Instead, a coure familiar is only available through the exalted feat Celestial Familiar (*BE* 41), and many DMs (and, often, players!) struggle with such excessively good PCs.

Answer (score 0):

It is questionable if Coure Eladrin has both low-light vision and darkvision:
It's type is Outsider. Outsiders usually gain darkvision 60'.
It has, among others, Eladrin subtype. While BoED (p. 168) itself doesn't list low-light vision and darkvision 60' as traits Eladrins possess, MM (which first mentions Eladrins, p. 93) does.
Also, example of Coure familiar given in BoED (p. 154) lists low-light vision and darkvision 60' as it's SQ.
And also, note that both type and subtype traits contain "unless otherwise noted in a creature’s entry" clause.

So, by very strict RAW, Coure do not have special vision forms, as Coure's statblock itself - creature’s entry - lacks them and consequently notes otherwise than type and subtype traits. Still, it probably isn't the intent.

---

It is even harder to tell about the light Coure sheds. It lacks spell level or equivalent for us to be able to match with effects needed to counter various darkness spells and effects. More of it, it is hard to say if this light is magical or not. There is just no separate description for it in Coure's abilities.

So, most probably, Coure's light is incapable of brightening the area of any spell with Darkness descriptor.

Comment: +1ed. You made me do more research. Nice catch. I'd've never known otherwise.